# Clear timeout with every function call Angular2 RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, scadalts

I have a http request which is being fired if user enters at least 4 characters inside the input and fires everytime he changes it's content (adding/removing letters). I want to add a timeout, that if user starts typing characters, the function will wait 1 second until it fires the request, to avoid a lot of requests when user is typing quickly. My attempt:

```
if (this.pointName.length >= 3) {
  let timer = function() {
    this.http.get(`./points.json`)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.pointsArray = res.json();
        });
    };
clearTimeout(timer); 
setTimeout(timer,1000);
```

My idea was to clear the timeout on every `keyup` event and set it once again.
But unfortunately it gives me an error, that `Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.

Is there any way to do it more efficientely? Maybe using RxJS? Anyways, I'm looking for a working solution. Thank you in advance.

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Point name"(keyup)="getPoints()">
```

Comment: The better way for your scenario is using the rxjs `debounce` operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why dont use debounceTime(500) instead of setTimeout.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html

Comment: If you have an account in egghead this video is so helpfull for your case. https://egghead.io/courses/build-an-angular-2-instant-search-component

Comment: How would it look like in my case? I have posted html code with keyup event.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/ycJKwFtmbcF5dupIHlOJ?p=preview It doesn't work correctly. Try to enter few chars quickly, it will fire the function without the delay.

Comment: Because you arent use debounce, You are use your function directly with keyup event, and dont use a debounce. Dont delete the term$ because here is where the debounce work https://plnkr.co/edit/3W7ZLtpaBL4Mo1nVvmJI

Comment: @silvelo It's amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd better use `Debounce` operator in RxJS.
And the problem in your code is that you should pass the `timer_id` into `clearTimeout` instead of the function.

```
if (this.pointName.length >= 3) {
  let timer = function() {
    this.http.get(`./points.json`)
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.pointsArray = res.json();
        });
    };
let timer_id = undefined;
clearTimeout(timer_id); 
timer_id = setTimeout(timer,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an RxJS Subject as a new member variable of your component

```
searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();
```

In your component's ngOnInit method, set up your observable,

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.searchTerm$
      .filter( value => value.length >= 3)
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .switchMap( val => {
         return this.http.get('./points.json')
                         .map(result => result.json());
       })
      .subscribe(result => .... // do what you want with the response );
}
```

In your HTML, change your keyup event binding to submit your input field's value

```
 <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Point name"(keyup)="getPoints(this.value)">
```

Then in your component's getPoints method,send a value into your subject$

```
getPoints(value) {
  this.subject$.next(value);
}
```

Basically, the observable you're creating does several things:

```
 searchTerm$
  .filter( value => value.length >= 3)   // 1 filter out search terms that are shorter than 3 characters
  .debounceTime(1000)                    // 2. only send events after no event comes for 1 sec
  .switchMap( val => {                    // 3. convert your value to the result of your http request
     return this.http.get('./points.json')
                     .map(result => result.json());
   })
  .subscribe(result => .... // do what you want with the response );
```